# Is firefox safe to use on Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: updates, firefox, internet, security, browser

While using Firefox on Ubuntu, I frequently run into warnings from various sites (recent examples: when checking gmail, www.hitrecord.org), that inform me that I am using an outdated/unsupported version of Firefox. I also read somewhere ( I can't remember where ), that Mozilla no longer provides updates for Firefox on Linux, and indeed, there doesn't seem to be any way to update Firefox on Ubuntu. I have tried the most official looking ppa I could find, and that just never seems to have any activity. Also, there is no 'in-browser' option to update, like on Windows. So my question is, is there truly no way to update Firefox on Linux? I am assuming the answer is no for now. I also have to wonder, if this is indeed the case, why?! I also note that there is no warning to this effect on Mozilla's download page for Firefox on Linux, which seems off.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Just upgraded to 15.10, but have been on 15.04 for the last 6 months or so. And still had the problem before that version too, I believe(14.10). I haven't used firefox in a while, but went back to it recently to see if this had been dealt with.

Comment: Define "safe" - Firefox and components are one of the more common security vulnerabilityies - See http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/ . There are tons of tutorials on how to harden Firefox.

Comment: "Mozilla no longer provides updates for Firefox on Linux" Where did you hear that?

Comment: What is Firefox current version in your system?

Comment: @muru I read it on some tech blog or other. I remember thinking it was very odd.

Comment: @Pilot6 it says 43.0.4

Comment: This means that the local repository mirror has not been updated yet. Choose another mirror or wait a few hours to get v. 44. But this is relevant if you installed FF a normal way using official repos.

Comment: You either have some extension installed that is causing problems, or there is some compromise between your computer and the server, that isn't necessarily firefox itself. I just opened gmail with 43.0.4, and it certainly does not complain about outdated versions or anything. It works just fine as expected.

Comment: @muru Ok, with regards to reading that Mozilla weren't providing updates for Firefox on Linux, I was mixed up. Here is the article I read. It's talking about adobe no longer providing updates for Flash in Firefox on Linux. http://www.howtogeek.com/193876/using-firefox-on-linux-your-flash-player-is-old-and-outdated/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox gets updates from Ubuntu official repositories.

If you have a supported version of Ubuntu, you should have the latest version of Firefox with security updates.

If this is not the case, then you have an EOL version of Ubuntu, or you did something wrong that prevents regular updates.

You can install the latest Firefox version by running in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Comment: This is very odd. I've never got updates. I notice now, there is a firefox-trunk, in the repositories. I will get that. I have always installed it from the website before now, and haven't been receiving any updates.

Comment: True , but  firefox has a lot of vulnerabilities and we do not know the OP risk tolerance. See http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/ , firefox is one of the more common vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Totem This means that you installed FF a wrong way. FF is installed in Ubuntu by default and gets updates. It is not supposed to be installed "from a web site".

Comment: @Totem If you installed FF from the website, then the onus is on you to keep it updated.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I had to keep reinstalling(I assume that's what this means) if I got it from the mozilla website. I have it sorted now. I removed the firefox I had and installed from the repo.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still experiencing the messages from gmail about having an outdated browser(and I've got the latest v.44.0), except now I also get a similar msg from youtube everytime I navigate there. I can still use youtube though, by reloading the page. Perhaps its something to do with flash.

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Firefox is [44.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/44.0/releasenotes/), released on January 26.

The current version of Firefox on Ubuntu **on any supported release** is [44.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox), and it's only been a day. I don't know what more you could ask for in the name of updates.

Comment: I see. I was confused, as I didn't know I had to update it myself, having installed it from the mozilla site. I just kept seeing 'unsupported/outdated' browser type messages on sites

Comment: I am using FF 43 and never got this type of messages anywhere. 44 has been released YESTERDAY.